# lazy evaluation with autoload vs require in ruby ?

Tags: ruby, lazy-loading

With my code I'm using autoload for lazy evaluation so I can load the program faster and load the files when needed, I'm not seeing so many people using it, but with Thin project I noticed autoload has been used widely, anyways just wanna know if there is any risk to use it .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`autoload` is [not threadsafe](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/921) and will be deprecated in the future versions of Ruby. Here is the [proof by Matz](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3036681) (creator of ruby).

Comment: Update: autoloading is thread-safe as of Ruby 2.0. For background, see [this article](https://ruby.awsblog.com/blog/tag/threads).